# Can't run Rails system test on WSL Ubuntu 18

Tags: ruby-on-rails, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm having issues running system tests on a fresh Rails 5.2 app from within Ubuntu 18.04 running on WSL.

I've installed `chromium-browser` on Ubuntu using `sudo apt-get install chromium-browser`.

test/application_system_test_case.rb:

```
class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase
  driven_by :selenium, using: :chrome, screen_size: [1400, 1400]
end
```

test/system/authentication_test.rb:

```
class AuthenticationTest < ApplicationSystemTestCase
  test 'prompting for credentials' do
    visit '/'
    assert new_user_session_path, current_path
  end
end
```

Running `rails test:system` crashes with the following:

```
2019-07-03 13:07:58 WARN Selenium [DEPRECATION] Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome#driver_path= is deprecated. Use Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Service#driver_path= instead.
Started with run options --seed 62037

AuthenticationTest
  test_prompting_for_credentials                                 ERROR (1.44s)
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError:         Selenium::WebDriver::Error::UnknownError: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: crashed
          (unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
          (The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/chromium-browser is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
            test/system/authentication_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:AuthenticationTest>'
```

If I change the Chrome path to point to my Windows Chrome install by adding the following to the base system test class:

`Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome.path = '/mnt/c/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe'`

When I run `rails test:system` it opens up two console windows and two Chrome windows.

Chrome throws an error "Failed to load extension from C:\tmp.com.google.\Internal. Manifest file is missing or unreadable".

The console windows both have the following errors:

```
[14148:9072:0703/131126.030:ERROR:database.cc(1601)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 1: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA auto_vacuum
[14148:9072:0703/131126.034:ERROR:database.cc(1601)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 1: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE
[14148:9072:0703/131126.040:ERROR:database.cc(1601)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 1: database is locked, sql: SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=? AND name=?
[14148:9072:0703/131126.044:ERROR:database.cc(1601)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 1: database is locked, sql: SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=? AND name=?
[14148:9072:0703/131126.048:ERROR:database.cc(1601)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 1: database is locked, sql: CREATE TABLE meta(key LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, value LONGVARCHAR)
[14148:6880:0703/131126.217:ERROR:backend_impl.cc(1437)] Unable to map Index file
[14148:10312:0703/131126.230:ERROR:cache_util_win.cc(21)] Unable to move the cache: The system cannot find the file specified. (0x2)
[14148:10312:0703/131126.230:ERROR:cache_util.cc(141)] Unable to move cache folder \\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\tmp\.com.google.Chrome.HgtI05\Default\Cache to \\wsl$\Ubuntu-18.04\tmp\.com.google.Chrome.HgtI05\Default\old_Cache_000
[14148:10312:0703/131126.230:ERROR:disk_cache.cc(178)] Unable to create cache
[14148:9072:0703/131126.233:ERROR:database.cc(1601)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 1: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA auto_vacuum
[14148:9072:0703/131126.237:ERROR:database.cc(1601)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 1: database is locked, sql: PRAGMA journal_mode=TRUNCATE
[14148:9072:0703/131126.241:ERROR:database.cc(1601)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 1: database is locked, sql: SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=? AND name=?
[14148:9072:0703/131126.245:ERROR:database.cc(1601)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 1: database is locked, sql: SELECT 1 FROM sqlite_master WHERE type=? AND name=?
[14148:9072:0703/131126.249:ERROR:database.cc(1601)] Cookie sqlite error 5, errno 1: database is locked, sql: CREATE TABLE meta(key LONGVARCHAR NOT NULL UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY, value LONGVARCHAR)
```

and the test crashes with:

```
AuthenticationTest
  test_prompting_for_credentials                                 ERROR (62.19s)
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError:         Selenium::WebDriver::Error::SessionNotCreatedError: session not created
        from tab crashed
          (Session info: chrome=75.0.3770.100)
            test/system/authentication_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:AuthenticationTest>'
```

Comment: I'm having a similar issue, and have gotten to this point only after ignoring the advice (elsewhere) to point at the Windows installation of chrome through a symbolic link, as that doesn't work because it doesn't make it past the attempt to determine the version of the running instance of `google-chrome`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update for WSL2:**

- Change the `CHROMEDRIVER_URL` to use the windows host's IP address as localhost refers to the VM itself in WSL2:

  ```
  WINDOWS_HOST = `cat /etc/resolv.conf | grep nameserver | awk '{ print $2 }'`.strip
  CHROMEDRIVER_URL = "http://#{WINDOWS_HOST}:9515/"
  ```
- Start chromedriver with `chromedriver --allowed-ips`. This will cause it to bind to `0.0.0.0` instead of `127.0.0.1` and allow connections from the WSL2 VM.
- Add a Windows firewall rule to allow incoming connections for port 9515.

**Original Answer:**

With help from this [post](https://ngauthier.com/2017/09/rails-system-tests-with-headless-chrome-on-windows-bash-wsl.html) I was able to get it working. You don't need to install `chromium-browser` or any additional Ubuntu packages. In case this helps others, here's what I did:

1. Download [chromedriver](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/) and place it somewhere that's part of the system path (e.g. 'C:\Windows') or create a new folder and add it to the system path variable.
2. Rename it from `chromedriver.exe` to `chromedriver`. Ensure WSL can access it by running `chromedriver -v` from a bash console.
3. Set the following options in the `ApplicationSystemTestCase`:

```
require 'test_helper'

CHROMEDRIVER_URL = 'http://localhost:9515/'

class ApplicationSystemTestCase < ActionDispatch::SystemTestCase

  Capybara.register_driver :selenium_remote_chrome do |app|
    options = Selenium::WebDriver::Chrome::Options.new
    options.add_argument('--start-maximized')

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
      app,
      browser: :remote,
      url: CHROMEDRIVER_URL,
      desired_capabilities: :chrome,
      options: options
    )
  end

  Capybara.configure do |config|
    # Match what's set for URL options in test.rb so we
    # can test mailers that contain links.
    config.server_host = 'localhost'
    config.server_port = '3000'
  end

  driven_by :selenium_remote_chrome

end
```

3. In a bash console, start the chromedriver server by running `chromedriver`.
4. In another bash console, run your system tests with `rails test:system`.